# Wordpress get_page 'read more' tag

Tags: wordpress

So I want to use the read more tag here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

But I'm using the get_page function as such:

```
$page_id = 1;
$include = get_page($page_id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content',$include->post_content);
```

When I've inserted the more tag via the page WYSIWYG it gets ignored when I echo $content.

I think I need to add something into apply_filters but I'm not sure what

Comment: are you trying to use `get_page` function and retrieve post_excerpt?

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking to get the post_excerpt, more a truncated post_content via the get_page function

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `post_content` to `post_excerpt` to echo the WYSIWYG excerpt

```
        $page_id = 1;
        $include = get_page($page_id);
        $content =  apply_filters('the_content',$include->post_excerpt); 
        echo $content;
```

Comment: That works if you add: "add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );" to functions.php and then add in an excerpt into the page via the separate WYSIWYG but it doesn't achieve the original issue in that it's not truncating the content. But I'll probably go with this solution if the alternative method can't be done?

Comment: i didnt have to add any support to my functions page with my code above

Comment: but i see what you mean, you want the ---more--- separator inside of the content field

Comment: Yep, that's right, the ---more--- separator inside of the content field. Any ideas?

Comment: i get both the content and excerpt, so my page looks like `<p>content</p><p>excerpt</p>` maybe you can use javascript to hide the excerpt? such as anything after `<!--more -->` is hidden until click of any div, etc